# Sharepoint file library : not enough free space

Tags: document-library

I am using a document-library component (on SP online) : currently 7.4 GB are used.
I want to copy a folder (4.71 GB) but I have an error message whitch says me that there is not enough free space on the disk (sharepoint disk).
Where can I change that ?

Comment: What is GO? Is that a typo for GB? What version and flavour of SharePoint? Online? On Premises? Please, if you need help you have to provide as much detail as possible about your setup.

Comment: Edited : Sharepoint Online. GigaByte.

Answer (score 0):

Your Site Collection may have a quota, probably 10GB. Contact your Office 365 Tenant Admin and find out if you have a quota on your Site Collection, and if they will increase it for you.

Comment: Im tenant Admin and my quota is 300GB. Seems like I have found the solution : A folder was wrong (Contains a dot in the name). Strange behaviour.